# Format for DayMMMYY in Excel

Tags: excel

For dates like 3/1/2015 and 3/13/2015 I need the format to be 01MAR15  and 13MAR2015

Do you know how to get this format in Excel using formulas?

The months are

JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC

Thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting to alter data in a different cell or just render the display as the abbreviated month?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft site](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Custom-Date-and-Time-formats-for-the-FORMAT-Function-DAX-dc60287d-5123-4521-840c-05b3c301e09f) indicates that mmm is  abbreviated month so `ddmmmyyyy` should work as a format on a cell containing a valid date.

and here's a shot showing it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the date is in cell A1, you would use the below for a formula.

```
=Text(A1,"ddmmmyyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

in 1 example you have 15 and the other you have 2015

use these if you want the result in a different cell
=Text(A1,"ddmmmyy")

=Text(A1,"ddmmmyyyy")

otherwise , select the cells, > right click> format cells> number tab>custom>

enter in  DDMMMYY or DDMMMYYY and press ok

Answer (score 0):

I suspect strings and that language is the issue so suggest:

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1),3),"/",""))=1,"0"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1),3),"/",""),SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1),3),"/",""))&CHOOSE(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1),"JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC")&RIGHT(A1,2)
```

Oops. Forgot to mention that for the year to show as four digits (your second example rather than your first), change the final `2` above (next to last character) to `4`.